# View [emails.user-verification] not found in production

Tags: laravel

When sending an email, I always get this error when I push the latest changes to my production server.

After 30 minutes, the error is gone and emails can be sent.

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. On post-deployment I am running these commands -

```
sudo php artisan cache:clear
sudo php artisan config:cache
sudo php artisan view:cache
sudo php artisan optimize:clear
sudo php artisan route:cache
sudo php artisan migrate --force
sudo php artisan db:seed --force
sudo php artisan optimize:clear
sudo php artisan storage:link
sudo php artisan queue:restart
```

Email verification file -

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewUserVerification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $theme = 'primary';

    public $newUser;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($newUser)
    {
        $this->newUser= $newUser;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Verify Email Address - '.$this->newUser->name)
                    ->markdown('emails.user-verification');
    }
}
```

and my markdown file at (resources.views.email.user-verification)

```
@component('mail::layout')

{{-- Header --}}
@slot('header')
@component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
@endslot

{{-- Body --}}
# Hi,

Please verify your email

@component('mail::button', ['url' => url('/s/verify/'.$newUser->email_verification_token), 'color' => 'primary'])
Verify Email Address
@endcomponent


{{-- Footer --}}
@slot('footer')
@component('mail::footer')
© {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name') }}. @lang('All rights reserved.')
@endcomponent
@endslot
@endcomponent
```

The error I am receiving on the failed job -

```
{
    "class": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "message": "View [emails.user-verification] not found.",
    "code": 0,
    "file": "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137",
    "trace": [
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:79",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php:137",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php:381",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php:358",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php:270",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php:211",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Localizable.php:19",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php:212",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php:307",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php:253",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/PendingMail.php:124",
        "/var/app/current/app/Jobs/WelcomeUser.php:37",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:36",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php:41",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:93",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:37",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:651",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php:128",
        "/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:141",
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: In you resources.views.email.user-verification you must name the file user-verification.blade.php, have you done this?

Comment: Also you try to use `markdown('emails.user-verification');` but state that the view is saved in `resources/views/email` so is it `email` or `emails` please check.

Comment: @geertjanknapen it is `emails`. I made a typo.

Comment: @dz0nika yes, the file name is user-verification.blade.php. Everything works in localhost and on the server after 30 minutes. But when I push the latest version I get the view not found error for 30 minutes.

Comment: Then that is the time it takes for your server to update everything.